# Play framework templeting error

Tags: templates, playframework-2.0, rendering

Im new to the play framework and came from Django. I am going through the tutorial found here:http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaTodoList and ran into a bug. When I try getting the task form to render, I get this on my page when it loads:

BaseScalaTemplate(play.api.templates.HtmlFormat$@423302dd) (taskForm ("label"))

I assume this means the form isnt rendering right? Im sure this is just a simple error but I cannot figure out why this is happening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you've got a space between `@inputText` and `(taskForm("label"))`, eg:

```
@form(routes.Application.newTask) {

    @inputText (taskForm("label")) 

    <input type="submit" value="Create">

}
```

It should be:

```
@form(routes.Application.newTask) {

    @inputText(taskForm("label")) 

    <input type="submit" value="Create">

}
```

Putting a space there makes the template parser think that the expression ends at the end of `@inputText`, and treats the rest of that line as plain text that's meant to be displayed statically in the resulting HTML.

Comment: Thanks so much! Thats exactly what it was